# In psynet4 audio stop working for certain experiments

Tags: python

I am running psynet, and the experiments seems to work fine, however no audio is played.  For example, hearing test is stopped working for me: no sound is played. Tried two different computers. Did anyone experience such an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Run `dallinger generate-constraints` in the (correct) experiment directory; this will solve the problem.